# without pointer C++ string how to expression string is nullptr?

Tags: java, c++, null

On C++ string can expression two case :

```
1. string flag;                     /* empty string */
1. string flag = "Other content";   /* other string */
```

On Java String can expression three case :

```
1. String flag = NULL;              /* NULL */
2. String flag = "";                /* empty string */
2. String flag = "Other content";   /* other string */
```

On C++ can we expression the string as NULL (`nullptr`) ? if not use pointer .

My scene:
I got string data from mysql , mysql expression way same as Java for string , `NULL`/`empty`/`other` .

My data model is used for Mysql And nlohmann Json .

Comment: If you really need to distinguish between "the absence of a string" and "an empty string", you could use [std::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)

Comment: In java, everything is an object which in turn essentially points to the memory representing the object.  You can use a ref counting pointer to the string to get the same computational result.  You could also make a string of more than one character where the first character is null...

Comment: Thanks , std::optional is well pointer is whell , but use these way , I must to Self-compatible with nlohmann Json . 
maybe is my only way.

Answer (score 2):

So you can use `std::optional` to express this:

```
std::optional<std::string> null_string = std::nullopt; // this is the "null" state

if (optional_string) { /// Can be used like a null or bool type

std::optional<std::string> empty_string = ""; // This is the empty string
std::optional<std::string> other_string = "Other content"; // The full string
```

Just be aware, that to use string interfaces, you will need to get the value of the string with `.value()` or `operator*`:

```
void print_string(const std::string& s);

print_string(*other_string);
```

This requires you to check that the string is actually valid before calling or you will invoke undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The answer below is quite theoretical.
In practice usually there's no real need to distinguish between an empty string and a null one and using `std::string` as is is the best solution. And if you only need to add only the "nullabilty" to your C++ string you can use `std::optional` as mentioned in the comments and other answer.

---

Having said that:

In Java a `String` is a reference type, meaning variables like `flag` actually hold a reference to the `String` object (and the reference can be null). An object can have multiple references to it, and when this number becomes zero the object can be automatically destroyed.

If you want to achieve an overall similar behavior in C++, you can use [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) holding a `std::string`:

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>
//...
std::shared_ptr<std::string> s1 = nullptr;      // null string
std::shared_ptr<std::string> s2 = std::make_shared<std::string>("");    // empty string
std::shared_ptr<std::string> s3 = std::make_shared<std::string>("abs"); // non empty string
```

Comment: but you shouldn't right?  just use value semantics

Comment: @FantasticMrFox Added a preface about whether this construct is actually needed.

Answer (score 0):

> On C++ can we expression the string as NULL (nullptr) ?

No you can't . want to expression string as nullptr need string pointer

> On C++ can we expression the string as NULL (nullptr) ? if not use pointer .

Maybe std::optional is answer .

> My data model is used for Mysql And nlohmann Json .

0. assume select `std::optional<string> flag`
1. for mysql  , you can expression string NULL , `flag = nullopt`
2. for nlohmann Json , you must to compatible with `std::optional`

   ```cpp
   namespace nlohmann {
     /* https://github.com/nlohmann/json#how-do-i-convert-third-party-types */
     template <typename T>
     struct adl_serializer<std::optional<T>> {
         static void to_json(json& j, const std::optional<T>& opt) {
           if(opt.has_value()) {
               // this will call adl_serializer<T>::to_json which will
               // find the free function to_json in T's namespace!
               j = opt.value();
           } else {
               j = nullptr;
           }
         }

         static void from_json(const json& j, std::optional<T>& opt) {
             if (j.is_null()) {
               opt = std::nullopt;
             } else {
               opt = j.get<T>(); // same as above, but with
                                 // adl_serializer<T>::from_json
             }
         }
     };
   }
   ```

> Other things

1. Copy form @wohlstad `In Java a String is a reference type, meaning variables like flag actually hold a reference to the String object (and the reference can be null).`

---

My Reference :

1. https://github.com/nlohmann/json/issues/1749
2. https://www.kdab.com/jsonify-with-nlohmann-json/